# Connect to Mysql, driver not found

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to connect my java code with mysql via JDBC. It gives me error

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:msyql://localhost:3306/fruitfarm
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at fruitFarm.DBRunner.getConnection(DBRunner.java:20)
    at fruitFarm.DBRunner.main(DBRunner.java:27)
```

I've downloaded the driver and I used eclipse to add to the build path.

Answer (score 2):

wrong URI

`jdbc:msyql` => `jdbc:mysql`

[Official driver documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) has an example